# Is it possible to conquer an enemy system and not settle it?

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

I want to destroy an AI player that I am at war with but I don't necessarily want all of his systems.  Is there a way to just destroy and not settle an enemy system?

Comment: You can capture the system and then build a structure that destroys the system, can't remember the name but its in the military tree. Commenting because I'm not sure if you can destroy it prior to capturing

Comment: @Lawton see Oblivious Sage's answer.

Comment: @rsegal I posted before him, but he remembered the name

Comment: Yeah, I was just making sure you saw it. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes.**

In the upper tree, on the left edge about 1/3 of the way up, there is a tech called Plasma Cage; it costs 1350 science to research. It grants the ability to build a system "improvement" called the Plasma Raze Grid. This improvement always takes 1 turn to build, no matter how little production a system has (so a just-conquered system with 1 population, negative happiness, and no production can still build it in 1 turn). Once completed, it destroys all improvements in the system, removes all population in the system, and gives you a colony ship.

Comment: There we are. That's what I was thinking about. I also had a notion that there was a related tech 1/3 of the way up on the right, but can't remember what it is if it exists at all.

Comment: Decon Droids or something like that. They don't do anything to the population in the system, just remove all improvements, but unlike the Plasma Raze Grid they give you dust for the improvements they remove.

Comment: Does it give you a single colony ship or one colony ship per point of population in the system?

Comment: @Chris I *believe* it only gives you a single colony ship, but I don't know for sure. Probably it is just one, because more would make the Pilgrims' racial ability less unique.

Comment: @ObliviousSage: Fair enough. If I remember I'll test it. And I'm only on my second game currently so no idea what the Pilgrims's racial is so I'll go look that up too. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes! There are numerous technologies for ransacking enemy systems as of Disharmony. I believe you're most interested in the special weapons (last) category.

- Vanilla bombardment: captures system. Not what you want if you don't want to own the system (e.x. if you're having happiness trouble).
- Bombs: New to Disharmony, bombs are a targeted weapon to abrade an enemy system into a more *manageable* state:

  - Anti-population: reduces population of planets
  - Anti-structure: removes orbital structures built in system
- Boats: New to Disharmony, all fighters and bombers can attack a system, even when they're configured for space action. There are higher levels of boats (shielded fighers, heavy bombers, etc) that I haven't been able to try yet.

  - Fighters: anti-boat, meager damage against ships and capture rate on systems
  - Bombers: anti-ship, decent damage against ships and capture rate on systems
- Special weapons: New to Disharmony, there are a few weapons of stupendous, system-cleansing power. These are about a third of the way up the Warfare tree, more towards the edges. One is called Plasma Cage, and is apparently a "system improvement" that razes all population and structure from a system. The other is called Deconstructor Drones, and will convert all system improvements into Dust but leave the population untouched. (Thanks Oblivious Sage!)